# R create matrix from one variable

Tags: r, variables, matrix, vector

I would like to create a matrix from one variable in my data frame. Each cell of matrix will be filled like this:

```
sum(Rin1,Rin2)/sum(Rin),...,sum(Rin1,Rin28)/sum(Rin)
sum(Rin2,Rin3)/sum(Rin),...,sum(Rin2,Rin28)/sum(Rin)
```

I use this script but it didn't work for me:

```
# Keep one column that has proportion of Rin=Tdin/User.in 
df.in <- df[,c(5)]
# Create matrix for rows' combination
a<-t(combn(28,2))
# Create empty matrix according length of rows
output <- matrix ('',28,28)
# Fill matrix with sum of rows divide sum of Rin 
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  # I came up with this line from my previous work! 
  output[cbind(a[i,][1],a[i,][2])] <-unlist(intersect(df.in[a[i,]][1],df.in[a[i,]][2]))
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Sample data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                .Label = c("Political.Issue", "Women.s.Rights", "Workers..Rights"), 
                class = "factor"), Kcore.in = c(0, 1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 21, 
                22, 25,28, 30, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 82), Tdin = c(2090, 3217, 6110, 32427,6612, 3425, 11940,
                17985, 1998, 882, 8661, 3228, 701, 656, 269,393, 7737, 339, 6456, 1950, 99, 302, 43320, 1087,
                3655, 2103,562, 2135), User.in = c(4723L, 183L, 87L, 62L, 24L, 13L, 13L,25L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 
                2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L,4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Rin = c(0.442515350412873,
                17.5792349726776,70.2298850574713, 523.016129032258, 275.5, 263.461538461538,918.461538461538,
                719.4, 285.428571428571, 441, 962.333333333333,358.666666666667, 350.5, 328, 269, 393, 595.153846153846, 
                169.5,2152, 650, 99, 302, 10830, 1087, 1827.5, 1051.5, 562, 1067.5)), .Names = c("Subject","Kcore.in", "Tdin", 
                "User.in", "Rin"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Subject", 
                drop = TRUE, indices = list( 0:27), group_sizes = 28L, biggest_group_size = 28L, labels = structure(list(Subject = 
                structure(1L, .Label = c("Political.Issue", "Women.s.Rights","Workers..Rights"), class = "factor")), 
                row.names = c(NA,-1L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Subject", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Subject"))
```

Comment: `outer(df$Rin, df$Rin, '+') / sum(df$Rin)` or `( df$Rin + matrix(df$Rin, nr=length(df$Rin), nc=length(df$Rin), byrow=TRUE) ) / sum(df$Rin)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
out <- matrix(NA, nrow = dim(df)[1], ncol = dim(df)[1])

sum <- sum(df$Rin)
for (t1 in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  for (t2 in 1:dim(df)[1]){
    out[t1, t2] <- sum(df$Rin[t1], df$Rin[t2])/sum
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @PejoPhylo . I check your output and it didn't give the right number. For example; The number in matrix [3,2] is 87.80912 but it should be 0.00330 . Row 2 in Rin is 17.5792350 and Row 3 in Rin is 70.2298851 so the intersection of these two rows in matrix [3,2] should be [(70.22+17.57)/26569.17]= 0.0033 . I hope that this explanation makes it clear for you.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to divide each entry by the sum. I edited my answer. It should be correct now.

Comment: PS. You wanna use `matrix(NA_real_, ...)` not just `NA` to avoid a fully copy of that matrix. See http://www.jottr.org/2014/06/matrixNA-wrong-way.html